# Detect if X is running and if it's usable for application

Tags: posix, xserver

On a POSIX-compliant system, how do one detect if X is running and if it's usable for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$DISPLAY` has a value, and try to connect the the server at that address.